# Does -XX:PermSize exists on an Oracle JVM is HotSpot 64bit Server VM?

Tags: java, jvm

I am a bit confused because the Oracle [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) Documentation does not mentioned the parameter `-XX:PermSize`.

But in the web you will find many references of the paremter, for example the [Reference for IBM WAS 6.0 Express](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tprf_tunejvm.html), refer this paremeter explicite for SUN HotSpot VMs. And even the (Sun/Oracle) [Java SE 6 Performance White Paper](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html) use that parameter.

So my question is: Does this parameter exist for an Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)?

Comment: You could just try it. The JVM should tell you when it doesn't recognize that option (at least it told me there was no `HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak` in Java 6 HotSpot: "Unrecognized VM option ...").

Comment: @Thomas: The vm seams to recognize it. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the JVM will tell you of any unrecognized options and prints `Unrecognized VM option ...` before exiting. If `-XX:PermSize` is not recognized, it shouldn't start at all and thus you might just test it.